# How can I add dynamic text display to output panel?

Tags: linqpad

I have a few scripts that I use for scanning file systems, and they run for a long time with minimal perceptible output.  What I'd like to do is show a current path in the output panel but without filling it with junk output.

Currently I'm using `Util.ProgressBar` to give some sort of feedback, but would like a solution that doesn't occupy quite so much space with things I have no use for.

I've tried creating and dumping a `System.Windows.Forms.Label` and various other controls but this appears to create a new `OutputPanel` that only shows up after the query execution is complete, which is not what I need.

Is there a way to achieve this or do I need to beg Joe to add something new?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `DumpContainer`:

```
// Create and dump the container
var container = new DumpContainer().Dump();

// Update its content as often as you need to
container.Content = ...
```

The displayed value will change in the Results output panel every time you change the container's content.

Comment: Excellent, thanks Thomas.  Exactly what I was after.